# How to make a pdf reader plugin in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-plugin

I want to create an open source pdf reader plugin in Flutter from scratch. I need a guide to approach forward.

Comment: 1) read the pdf file 2) show it on screen. What are you expecting anyone to really tell you? How far are you with this? And if you haven't even started, then you have posted your question several days (or weeks) too early.

Comment: Is it possible to work with Poppler or any other libraries which are written in C++?

Comment: It's possible to interop with C/C++, everything is in official documentation - https://docs.flutter.dev/development/platform-integration/c-interop

Answer (score 0):

[The official documentation](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/packages-and-plugins/developing-packages) is always a good starting point. After you read it and get the overall impression on plugin development, I'd go to pub.dev and [search for existing pdf](https://pub.dev/packages?q=pdf) packages, and look how they are done. Your package will be no different from existing implementations. You might find tons of PDF viewers there, so, instead of building yet another plugin, pick the existing one and improve it. That's how OSS works, right?

P.S. welcome to SO!

Comment: I am trying to make Flutter plugin for [it](https://api.kde.org/okular/html/okular_generators.html). But I can't understand about .json and . desktop steps.